# How to get multiple xvfb GraphicsDevice from java

Tags: java, xvfb

I want to get a lot of screenshots from java in headless server.
To do this, my plan is below.

1. Use Xvfb for virtual screen.
2. To reduce tasks in queue fast, open multiple xvfb.
3. To get screenshots from java, use java.awt.Robot#createScreenCapture.
   (A constructor of java.awt.Robot require target java.awt.GraphicsDevice)

A problem is that xvfb screen devices aren't listed by java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment#getScreenDevices().

Code is something like this.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/GraphicsEnvironmentgetScreenDevices.htm

```
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] screenDevices = ge.getScreenDevices();
    for (int i = 0; i < screenDevices.length; i++)
      System.out.println(screenDevices[i].getIDstring());
  }
}
```

Terminal:

```
% Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
% Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
```

Actually, I tested above equivalent code from Clojure's repl on MBA(Mac OSX 10.6.8) and HP2140 (Ubuntu 10.04).

```
(seq (.getScreenDevices (java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment/getLocalGraphicsEnvironment))
;=> (#<CGraphicsDevice CGraphicsDevice[screen=0]>)
```

I think two xvfb devices should be listed.
Is there a way to get xvfb GraphicsDevice?

Thanks.